# Data is not passing to server through volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm trying to send data to the server to check login by using volley but data is not being received at the server end. I'm getting an error message

> Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp2\htdocs\serverconnect.php on line 5

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

        StringRequest stringRequest  = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://192.168.43.144/mr_loc_tracker.php",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i("Server Response",response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i("Server Error Response",error.toString());
                }
            }
        ){

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
                params.put("username","Pranay");


                return params;
            }
        };
        MySingleton.getInstance(MainActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Code of MySingleton.java:

```
public class MySingleton {
    private static MySingleton mInstance;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private  static Context mCtx;

    private MySingleton(Context context){
        mCtx = context;
        requestQueue = getRequestQueue();
    }

    public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(Context context){
        if (mInstance==null)
        {
            mInstance= new MySingleton(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public <T>void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> request){
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (requestQueue==null)
        {
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());

        }
        return requestQueue;
    }
}
```

Code of serverconnect.php

```
 <?php

 $username = $_GET["username"];

 echo $username;

 ?>
```

I'm getting the error

> Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp2\htdocs\serverconnect.php on line 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `$_GET` -> `$_POST` and `Request.Method.GET` -> `Request.Method.POST`

If you want to stay with `GET` method remove the `getParams()` function, you have to pass param in your url ex.: `http://192.168.43.144/mr_loc_tracker.php?username=doe`

Answer (score 0):

Upload your (php) server connection codes and database names and all

Comment: My main problem is I'm not even receiving the value in    $username = $_GET["username"];

Comment: thats what upu want to use  get query for php server

Comment: Please help me in receiving data at the server end. I have not written further code. If I'm not able to receive data from my application then how could I move further

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 require 'config.php'; // your databsee configuration file
 $username = $_GET['username'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users(user table) where email='$email'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    $status = "exist";
}
echo json_encode(array("response"=>$status));
mysqli_close($con);

 ?>
```